# Using google sheets api in a reactJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Good morning everyone! For context, I am trying to insert some information using the google sheets api via react! I have the following code testing to start adapting to a web application made in react:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');


let creds = null;
try {
  creds = require('./credentials-teste.json');
} catch (err) {
  throw `Failed to load credentials.json: ${err}`;
}
//prepare oauth2 client
const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  creds.client_id,
  creds.client_secret,
  'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
);
auth.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'DUMMY',
  expiry_date: 1,
  refresh_token: creds.refresh_token,
  token_type: 'Bearer'
});

module.exports = auth;
```

The above code works very well, being called as follows:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const auth = require('./credentials-load');

async function run() {
  //create sheets client
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
  //append a range of values (3x3 grid, starting at A5)
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    spreadsheetId: '12F2MKo2gbNJ2NJGPVKIpjQ2gQdKMshW2KJ...',
    range: 'Pagina1!A1:C3',
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    resource: {
      values: [
        ['Teste 1.1', 'Teste 1.2', 'Teste 1.3'],
        ['Teste2.1', 'Teste2.2', 'Teste2.3'],
        ['Teste3.1', 'Teste3.2', 'Teste3.3']
      ]
    }
  });
  //print results
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));
}

run().catch(err => console.error('ERR', err));
```

But when I put it in a react application, I ran into the following error:

> util.js?3022:602 Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function at Object.promisify (util.js?3022:602) at eval (discovery.js?7b7f:21) at Object../node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/discovery.js (main.js:8194) at webpack_require (main.js:20) at eval (index.js?36ad:23) at Object../node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/index.js (main.js:8218) at webpack_require (main.js:20) at eval (index.js?8bcd:16) at Object../node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/abusiveexperiencereport/index.js (main.js:8373) at webpack_require (main.js:20)

The code was as follows in the application in reactJS:

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

//export default function auth() {

export const auth = () => {
  let creds = null;
  try {
    creds = require('./credentials-teste.json');
  } catch (err) {
    throw `Failed to load credentials.json: ${err}`;
  }
  //prepare oauth2 client
  const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    creds.client_id,
    creds.client_secret,
    'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
  );
  auth.setCredentials({
    access_token: 'DUMMY',
    expiry_date: 1,
    refresh_token: creds.refresh_token,
    token_type: 'Bearer'
  });
  //};
};
```

With the call to it looking like this:

```
async function testeAppend() {
    //create sheets client
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
    //append a range of values (3x3 grid, starting at A5)
    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      spreadsheetId: '12F2MKo2gbNJ2NJGPVKIpjQ2gQdKMshW2...',
      range: 'Pagina1!A1:C3',
      insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      resource: {
        values: [
          today,
          ,
          ,
          `${fnameTrim} ${lnameTrim}`,
          ,
          ,
          cnpj,
          ,
          fone,
          email.toLowerCase()
        ]
      }
    });
    //print results
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));
  }
```

It compiles correctly, but that error keeps showing up and I'm already a few hours back on that error and I can't solve it! It's just to insert a data using google sheets, I didn't think I would have this headache hahahaha If someone can help me, I would appreciate it!